# ORA-01422 Error

Tags: oracle, exception, select

I ran into a problem today but I can't see what's wrong with my code. I made a procedure which contains a SELECT INTO which fetches 2 rows, and 2 variables. I took out some parts of the procedure otherwise it would get too long:

In the AS I declare a CURSOR, this selects all the records in table WINKEL.

```
  CURSOR v_winkels IS
    SELECT W.id
    FROM WINKEL W;
```

Oracle then later throws an ORA-01422 EXCEPTION here:

```
  FOR w IN v_winkels LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line('ID is ' || w.id);

    SELECT P.lat, P.lon
    INTO v_lat_winkel, v_lon_winkel
    FROM POSTCODE P, WINKEL W
    WHERE W.postcode_ID_FK = P.id
    AND W.id = w.id;
```

I don't see what's wrong here. I'm using Oracle XE 11.2 in Oracle SQL Developer.

EDIT: I already used a SELECT INTO with multiple variables, so I don't get why it doesn't work here. Example code:

```
  SELECT P.id, P.street, P.city
    INTO o_ID, o_straat, o_woonplaats
    FROM POSTCODE P
    WHERE P.postcode = i_postcode
    AND i_huisnummer BETWEEN P.minNumber AND P.maxNumber
    AND (P.numberType = v_even OR P.numberType = 'mixed')
    AND ROWNUM = 1;
```

Comment: You can't select two rows into a variable.  Need a cursor for that.  Also, why not just join the two tables and have one query/loop then?

Comment: @OldProgrammer I'll add some more info to the question.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Yes you're right, I just fixed it by adjusting the CURSOR itself to hold all the 3 variables. Thanks!